# How to dump html source into mongodb using pycurl

Tags: python, curl, pymongo

I want to download the html source of a web page using pycurl and store it in mongodb using pymongo.Can you please suggest me a way to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the PycURL documentation, you can get the HTML for a page:

```
import pycurl
from StringIO import StringIO

buffer = StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/')
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
c.close()
html = buffer.getvalue()
```

... and then insert it into a MongoDB collection:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.html
collection = db.html
collection.insert({'html':html})
```

Then, login to MongoDB and you can see the page:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
> show dbs
html            0.078GB
> use html;
switched to db html
> db.html.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("545b1655164a1b2f92300001"), "html" : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>\n\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"\n    \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n\n<head>\n  <title>PycURL Home Page</title>\n  <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\" />\n  <meta name=\"author\" content=\"Kjetil Jacobsen, Markus F.X.J. Oberhumer\" />\n [... page truncated ...] </body>\n</html>\n" }
```

You may find that Python's `requests` package is a bit easier to use than PycURL: http://docs.python-requests.org/

Comment: Thank you Alex Woolford. This helped me. I generally use urllib2 for requests but this is something i specifically got to do using pycurl.